# Can we make the properties in a Custom UITableViewCell as public

Tags: xamarin.ios, xib, custom-cell

I have created a Custom UITableViewCell, on the xib I have added 3 UILabels for which outlets are also added. Within the custom class I am able to access all the three. Will it be possible to have a public access specifier to these items?

Comment: Please accept an answer if this has helped you. Or answer your own question. Knowing that this is fixed will help others in the future facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can do this. In your custom `UITableViewCell` class make some public access properties to expose Labels to the outside world as given below:

```
public class YourCustomCell : UITableViewCell
{
   public UILabel MyFirstLabel
   {
      get { return myFirstLableOutletInstance; }
   }

   public UILabel MySecondLabel
   {
      get { return mySecondLableOutletInstance; }
   }
}
```

Then outside of this class, where you instantiate this cell object, you can access them via : `cell.MyFirstLabel;`

Ex. If you want to set TextColor of this label, you can do like:

```
cell.MyFirstLabel.TextColor = UIColor.Red;
cell.MySecondLabel.TextColor = UIColor.Blue;
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the outlets from the designer file to your `CustomViewCell` and mark them public.

The moved `Outlet` won't be generated again in the designer so it's save to delete them and remove the `GeneratedCode` attribute.

```
[Outlet]
public UILabel Title { get; set; }
```